# Maven Tycho build fails

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, osgi, tycho

I'm working on an OSGi-based project. I've got following code in one of the methods:

```
private void loadResourceSet(final URI... uris)
{
    ResourceMirror resourceMirror = new ResourceMirror(resourceSet)
    {
        @Override
        protected void run(String taskName, IProgressMonitor monitor)
        {
            perform(uris);
        }
    };

    resourceMirror.begin(new NullProgressMonitor());
}
```

ResourceMirror is an abstract class from third-party plugin, it's code is avalible [here](http://git.eclipse.org/c/oomph/org.eclipse.oomph.git/tree/plugins/org.eclipse.oomph.setup.core/src/org/eclipse/oomph/setup/internal/core/util/ResourceMirror.java). So, projects runs well from the IDE (Eclipse), but when I try to build it with Maven Tycho, the build fails with following error:

```
[ERROR] ResourceMirror resourceMirror = newResourceMirror(resourceSet)
[ERROR] ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[ERROR] The type new ResourceMirror(){} must implement the inherited 
abstract method WorkerPool<ResourceMirror,URI,ResourceMirror.LoadJob>.createWorker(Object, int, boolean)
```

But from the ResourceMirror source it seems that it implements all required methods. So, what I am doing wrong? My other plugins that use same third-party plugins build successfully. Thanks for your help!